# C++ Iterators and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, iterator

Have a quick question about what would be the best way to implement iterators in the following:

Say I have a templated base class 'List' and two subclasses "ListImpl1" and "ListImpl2". The basic requirement of the base class is to be iterable i.e. I can do:

```
for(List<T>::iterator it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); it++){
   ...
}
```

I also want to allow iterator addition e.g.:

```
for(List<T>::iterator it = list->begin()+5; it != list->end(); it++){
   ...
}
```

So the problem is that the implementation of the iterator for ListImpl1 will be different to that for ListImpl2. I got around this by using a wrapper ListIterator containing a pointer to a ListIteratorImpl with subclasses ListIteratorImpl2 and ListIteratorImpl2, but it's all getting pretty messy, especially when you need to implement operator+ in the ListIterator.

Any thoughts on a better design to get around these issues?

Comment: Why not use [`std::advance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/)?

Comment: Thanks, but say I need to I want to provide a more efficient operator+ than just using operator++ repeatedly. Presumably I still have the same problem?

Comment: The distinction between a forward iterator (what `std::advance()` is for) and a random access iterator is that a forward iterator does not have an efficient `operator+` implementation (think linked list). This question implies an iterator which is statically random access, but which has dynamic behavior for that access.

Comment: That's correct - I would like dynamic behaviour for the random access. I don't see why that would be a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can get away with making `List<T>::iterator` non-virtual, then delegating the virtualness off add to List makes things simple:

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
    virtual void add_assign(iterator& left, int right) = 0;

public:
    class iterator
    {
        const List* list;
        const T* item;
    public:
        iterator(const List* list, const T* item) : list(list), item(item) {}

        iterator& operator +=(int right)
        {
            list->add_assign(*this, right);
            return *this;
        }
        static iterator operator +(iterator const& left, int right)
        {
            iterator result = left;
            result += right;
            return result;
        }
    };

    virtual iterator begin() const = 0;
    virtual iterator end() const = 0;
};
```

Otherwise (if the iterators need to store significantly different data, for example), then you have to do the regular, boring pointer-to-implementation to get your virtualness:

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
    class ItImpl
    {
        virtual ItImpl* clone() = 0;
        virtual void increment() = 0;
        virtual void add(int right) = 0;
    };
public:
    class iterator
    {
        ItImpl* impl;
    public:
        // Boring memory management stuff.
        iterator() : impl() {}
        iterator(ItImpl* impl) : impl(impl) {}
        iterator(iterator const& right) : impl(right.impl->clone()) {}
        ~iterator() { delete impl; }
        iterator& operator=(iterator const& right)
        {
            delete impl;
            impl = right.impl->clone();
            return *this;
        }

        // forward operators to virtual calls through impl.
        iterator& operator+=(int right)
        {
            impl->add(right);
            return *this;
        }
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            impl->increment();
            return *this;
        }
    };
};

template<typename T>
static List<T>::iterator operator+(List<T>::iterator const& left, int right)
{
    List<T>::iterator result = left;
    result += right;
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
class MagicList : public List<T>
{
    class MagicItImpl : public ItImpl
    {
        const MagicList* list;
        const magic* the_magic;
        // implement ...
    };
public:
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(new MagicItImpl(this, begin_magic)); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(new MagicItImpl(this, end_magic)); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something very important among iterators, called Iterator Category:

- InputIterator
- OutputIterator
- ForwardIterator
- BidirectionalIterator
- RandomAccessIterator

Each category define an exact set of operations that are supported, efficiently, by the iterator.

Here, it seems you wish to turn down that powerful identification mechanism to create some kind of bastard category in which the operations are all present, but no guarantee is made on their efficiency.

I think your design smells.

Comment: I don't really see what you mean. It's just a random access iterator guaranteeing constant time.

Comment: Then `operator+` should be part of the interface (accepting a signed integer as its right hand side argument). What is your issue ?

Comment: The problem is that operator+ is returning an iterator, but iterator implementation is different in the two subclasses, so you have to hide  this implementation away inside a 'wrapper' iterator. My question was whether there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: It can be done easily: a pimpl class `iterator`, containing a pointer to a dynamically allocated object derived from an `iterator_interface` class (featuring a `clone` method). It means 2 classes + 1 per implementation.

Comment: That's the solution from the original post. I was just wondering if someone could suggest something cleaner, but the consensus seems to be that this is an OK way to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

> So the problem is that the
>   implementation of the iterator for
>   ListImpl1 will be different to that
>   for ListImpl2. I got around this by
>   using a wrapper ListIterator
>   containing a pointer to a
>   ListIteratorImpl with subclasses
>   ListIteratorImpl2 and
>   ListIteratorImpl2, but it's all
>   getting pretty messy, especially when
>   you need to implement operator+ in the
>   ListIterator.

This design is fine IMHO, I can't see anything messy about it. Except for equality and subtraction, operations of the iterator can be implemented by virtual function pretty easily, so you'll have something like

```
class ListIteratorInterface // abstract
{
protected:
  virtual Data& operator*()=0;
  // and other operations
};
class ListIteratorA;
class ListIteratorB; // implementation of the above
class ListIterator
{
  ListIteratorInterface* impl_;
public:
  // when you create this, allocate impl_ on the heap
  // operations, forward anything to impl_
};
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I have at the moment. Where it gets more messy is the implementation of operator+ in the ListIterator class. Because I need to return a new ListIterator and ListIteratorA/B, I guess I need to create a virtual clone() method in the ListIteratorInterface to create a new impl of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

You could store operator+ as a private virtual method in the base class, and have the iterator call that.

Alternatively, you could consider statically polymorphic list classes, rather than runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

> Say I have a templated base class 'List' and two subclasses "ListImpl1" and "ListImpl2"

What exactly do you gain by using inheritance here?

Comment: @jom: There are different kinds of polymorphism. The STL containers are based on "compile time polymorphism / static binding / genericity / templates", not the kind of polymorphism you seem to have in mind.

Comment: I'm talking about run-time polymorphism i.e. using List<T> is an interface with multiple implementations ListImpl1<T> and ListImpl2<T>, transparent to client code, although obviously there is static polymorphism here too.